# How does the release version of Roslyn implement immutable trees?

Tags: c#, tree, immutability, roslyn

I understand that the pre-release version of Roslyn implemented immutable trees as described in [this excellent blog post](https://ericlippert.com/2012/06/08/red-green-trees/) by Eric Lippert. However, that post ends with:

> The cost is that this system is complex and can consume a lot of memory if the "red" facades get large. We are at present doing experiments to see if we can reduce some of the costs without losing the benefits.

I'd like to ask what the outcome was for the release version. I've started examining the Roslyn [sources](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Src/Compilers/Core/Portable/Syntax/SyntaxNode.cs) but the code is fairly complex to follow.

What I'm interested in are the low-level design results regarding the costs mentioned above.

1. What is the cost of a single edit in terms of red/green nodes?
2. What optimizations have been made for other operations (e.g. delete, undo)?

Comment: I think it's easier to follow using this one: http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Syntax/SyntaxNode.cs,849dc6029695ef7b

Comment: Also have a look at the [BCL immutable collections](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Erik-Meijer-Immo-Landwerth-and-Andrew-Arnott-Immutable-Collections-for-NET) that were inspired by the Roslyn Red/Green trees.

Comment: @DaveShaw, I took a quick look at the link, and will watch the video. However the description page does not mention trees, but it does mention a number of other collection types.

Comment: Release version? Roslyn is still under development and no production-ready version has been released yet.

Comment: I meant the web release of code, which was after Microsoft turned Roslyn on in their own internal builds after years of development. I didn't mean production.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a fantastic look at Roslyn's performance and implementation of immutable trees by VSadov on discussion forums here: https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/541953

At a high level, he discusses concurrency, de-duplication of green nodes, de-duplication of terminals and de-duplication of strings within theses trees.

He also talks about the laziness of red trees. Instead of computing the red tree after every text change, the red tree is computed only when someone requests it.

Finally, he discusses the red tree and the fact that it's weak. I'd never used or seen the [`WeakReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference(v=vs.110).aspx) class, and VSadov provides a good overview of how it's used within the red tree. Basically, the garbage collector is allowed to clean up portions of the red tree and they can be recreated later if needed. I'm not familiar with the implementation, but Eric Lippert notes that the red tree facade can result in a large memory footprint. I imagine these `WeakReferences` help mitigate this problem to some degree.

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted your answer. Would be nice to get a definitive answer to how Undo is implemented, though.

Comment: useful discussion copy on [github](https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/Bliki/wiki/Roslyn-Immutable-Trees)

Answer (score 4):

At present we are still doing basically the same thing that Eric described.  We tried some experiments, but found that the cost to API clarity was too high to pay.  Instead, the main change we made was to reduce heap allocations and GC costs by making `SyntaxToken` into a struct in the red model.  This is a significant savings, since in average source files, roughly half of the nodes in the syntax tree are terminals (`SyntaxToken`s).  The green nodes are not structs, but on the other and, since they do not contain parent pointers or positions, they are interned - we share the same instance of the green node for all identical nodes (same trivia and text).

I'm not sure what you mean by "cost" of an edit.  Time/space/complexity/etc.  In general we have an incremental lexer which rescans the area affected by the edit.  Then we have an incremental parser, which in the best case reparses the statement which intersect with the newly lexed tokens and then re-builds the "spine" of the green tree back up to the root, while re-using the rest of the green nodes in the tree.  None of the red nodes are reusable by definition.  There is a new root node for the new tree, and it is reachable from any other node.

No other optimizations have been done in the compiler.  We re-use a cached tree in the IDE after an undo, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I understand that SyntaxNode == red node, GreenNode == green node. How does SyntaxToken fit into the tree structure?

Comment: So for an Undo there is an entire cached tree, i.e., a new tree for every single character insertion? That seems prohibitively expensive, so could you please clarify?

Comment: There is a "new tree" for every edit, but remember that most of the green nodes are shared across successive edits.  If the tree is of depth 'h', then on average only new O(h) green nodes are created.  There *could* be a distinct red node in each version of the tree, but red nodes are created lazily, and most of the time the IDE doesn't actually cause many of the red nodes to be realized, because it works after a slight delay in case of rapid successive edits.

Comment: SyntaxToken is effectively the "red" version for terminals in the language/leaves in the tree.  Making it a struct saves a bunch of allocations and reduces GC pressure.

Comment: Thanks, but your comments do not seem to address Undo, or am I missing something? Over the course of an editing session, I may make thousands of small changes, and Visual Studio allows me to undo to any level. That's why I don't think that each Undo revision corresponds to a different green tree, however small. I'm more inclined to believe that the UI does not use these trees at all for Undo, but rather the standard "compensating change" approach.

Comment: Oh, I understand now.  We do cache trees, based on the contents of the file, nut it isn't an unlimited cache.  On undo (or any edit) we check if a tree corresponding to the editor's content exists, and use it if it does, or else create a new tree with the incremental lexer and parser. Any time we create a new tree, we add it to the cache, which may cause other, less used trees to be evicted from the cache.

Comment: Got it. So undo/redo itself is handled by the editor, what you describe is an optimization to avoid re-creating trees if possible after an undo/redo has occurred. Correct?